# how to set the first row of a table as the default selectedRow on page Load using AngularJS?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table formed using AngularJS:

```
<table class="table" style="font-size:0.9em">
<tr>
<th><a href="" ng-click="sortField = 'FirstName'; reverse = !reverse">FirstName</a></th>
<th><a href="" ng-click="sortField = 'LastName'; reverse = !reverse">LastName</a>     
</th>
<th><a href="" ng-click="sortField = 'Grade'; reverse = !reverse">Grade</a></th>
<th><a href="" ng-click="sortField = 'Marks'; reverse = !reverse">Marks(%)<a></th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="r in value | filter:query |  orderBy:'-Marks':reverse"ng-class-odd="'tableOdd'"
ng-class-even="'tableEven'"
ng-click="graph(r)"
ng-class="{tractive: r === selectedRow}" >
<td>{{r.FirstName}}</td>
<td>{{r.LastName}}</td>
<td>{{r.Grade}}</td>
<td>{{r.Marks}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I need to set the first row of the table as the default selectedRow on initial page load.Also iam calling the graph() function on click event of the table.I need to execute the graph() on initial page load as well.Is it possible to do this using some Angular directive?

Comment: set `$scope.selectedRow === value[0]`, or whatever it ends up being if you want to use `orderBy`

Comment: where do i do this? in the ng-init directive ?

Comment: ever use ng-init in an actual application. only for doing quick and dirty examples

Comment: in my controller ,  $scope.value = getdata();                                           when i do $scope.selectedRow === value[0] it says selectedRow is not defined

Comment: Yes, you need to define it there, and assign it there. The controller is responsible for setting up the ViewModel, including what is considered defaultly selected or not. You *could* shove it down controller's throat with `ng-init` from the View, but that would not be a good idea

Comment: i need the default value of the selectedRow to be the first row of the table(which is sorted on Marks field on descending) and not value[0] which does not have objects in the sorted order.Anyways thanks for the comments

Comment: Then you should filter and order in the controller, and take the first element. Would the selected row change when you change ordering or if it is filtered out?

Comment: the selected row would change based on the ordering of the marks field .ie hisghest marks row would pop up first in the table.

Comment: i do that in this html file using this line : <tr ng-repeat="r in value | filter:query |  orderBy:'-Marks':reverse" ...how do i do this in the controller? use javascript to sort through the "value" object literally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question because it illustrates well the issue of separation of concerns.

**The View** is responsible for data presentation and user input. It can augment the data for presentation purposes (using Angular expressions and filters), but should avoid (where possible) defining the ViewModel.

**The Controller** is responsible for defining the ViewModel in a way that accommodates the View, but remains View-agnostic.

So, specifically, to your question. If the ordering of the table changes the "state" of the ViewModel and not only done for presentation purposes, then it should be done in the controller, rather than than in the View. In other words, if functionality of the app is affected by the order, like for example, setting the `selectedRow` or advancing the selected row to the next row (which only makes sense in the filtered array), then the ordering and its effects should be done in the controller.

```
app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope, $filter){
  var data = getData();

  $scope.sortField = ""; // unsorted
  $scope.reverse = false;
  $scope.query = undefined; // unfiltered

  $scope.$watchGroup(["query", "sortField", "reverse"], function(){
    $scope.sortedValues = filterAndSort();

    // set the selected row after sorting
    $scope.selectedRow = $scope.sortedValues.length && $scope.sortedValues[0];
  });

  function filterAndSort(){
    var filtered = $filter("filter")(data, $scope.query);
    return $filter("orderBy")(filtered, $scope.sortField, $scope.reverse);
  }
});
```

The HTML changes a bit:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    ...
    <th>
      <a href="" ng-click="sortField = 'Marks'; reverse != reverse;">
        Marks(%)
      </a>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="r in sortedValues" 
      ng-class="{tractive: r === selectedRow}">
     ...
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: could u explain that function filterAndSort() ?

Comment: i tried this...this is jus displaying the values[0] like i said before and not the sortedValues[0]...

Comment: `filterAndSort` does exactly the same filtering and sorting that you were doing in the View, using the `$filter` service. At first the array is not sorted, but if you change `sortField, it should resort and re-assign `$scope.selectedRow`

Comment: For anyone having issues implementing this, it should be return rather than $return